# How to read a json input in C# using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, aws-lambda, json.net

Im trying to read json coming into an AWS lambda function, part of the initial code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

// Assembly attribute to enable the Lambda function's JSON input to be converted into a .NET class.
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]

namespace DemoApp
{
    public class Function
    {
        public string FunctionHandler(dynamic input,ILambdaContext context)
        {
            dynamic results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(input);
            String customer = results.customer;
             .......
```

The incoming json is

```
{'customer': 'Test Customer',
 'phone': '0435 434 544',
 'asset': 'ASSET',
 'po': 'PO09876',
 'location': 'XYZ',
 'items': {'hose': [[{'goods': 'A231',
     'qty': '0.23',
     'backorder': '0.0',
     'unitprice': '0.0',
     'total': '0.0'},
    {'goods': 'B564',
     'qty': '1.0',
     'backorder': '0.0',
     'unitprice': '0.0',
     'total': '0.0'},
    {'goods': 'C544',
     'qty': '1.0',
     'backorder': '0.0',
     'unitprice': '0.0',
     'total': '0.0'}]],
  'items': []}}
```

I got an error `The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(string)' has some invalid arguments",`. How do I read json properly?

Comment: That "incoming JSON" isn't JSON. `dynamic input` isn't a `string input` (though a `string` could be passed in via this parameter, the compiler has no way to know if this will always be the case, or ever the case), which is the reason for the compiler error. Even if you fix that, you won't be able to deserialize that because it's not valid JSON.

Comment: @Llama Sample shown is missing quotes because I copied what was generated on another app, its proper json though when it goes into lambda because lambda only accepts json input. Or is there another reason why its not valid?

Comment: Nope, no other reason. I went through and added all the quotes and it looks just fine, so you should be good from that perspective.

Comment: @Llama Ok thanks. I've edited

Comment: The JSON you provided parses as JSON using the Newtonsoft's DeserializeObject call (I have a little tool I wrote that validates JSON or XML - yours passes)(.  But the problem you are having is that (as @Llama points out), you are calling `DeserializeObject<object>(string)` but passing a `dynamic` and not a string.  Cast the dynamic to a string (using either `(string)input` or `input as string` (the first will throw if input is not a string, the second will evaluate as null in that case) and you should be good to go

Comment: @Flydog57 Noted, thanks. Im still new to C# so struggling a bit. I hadnt realised `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` expects a string but I was passing it a json. After receiving the json I've now converted it to string and it works

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted my question :(

Comment: "A json" isn't really a thing in C#. What you have is a string in JSON format. But in a variable declared as an `object` or a `dynamic`; it's capable of holding anything. In this case, it's holding a reference to a string. You know that, and at runtime, that's what happens. But all the compiler knows is the `DeserializeObject` takes a variable of type string (or a string literal/constant). It looks and sees no way to implicitly (i.e.  automatically) convert your dynamic to a string, so it flags it as a compile error. By explicitly casting the variable to a string you satisfy the signature

Comment: @Flydog57 Got it, cheers

Answer (score 1):

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`expects a string so I've converted the json to a string and everything works.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

// Assembly attribute to enable the Lambda function's JSON input to be converted into a .NET class.
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]

namespace DemoApp
{
    public class Function
    {
        public string FunctionHandler(Object input,ILambdaContext context)
        {
            string jsonString = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(input);
            dynamic results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
            String customer = results.customer;
             .......
```